# Can I have a linen lining in a wool jacket?

Tags: halacha, clothing, shaatnez

Pretty straightforward: is it permissible to have a garment in which linen and wool fabrics are both present? Some examples would include the example in the title (linen lining in a wool jacket) and a linen collar or lapel in a wool suit (or vice-versa).

Comment: After posting my answer, I realized I'm not sure about your case - is the lining attached to the jacket, or just enclosed by it?

Answer (score 10):

This issue is a dispute of Rishonim.

The Rash to Kilayim 9:1 says the wool and linen must touch to be prohibited.

The Rambam (Kilayim 10:3) holds even if they are not touching, as long as they are in the same garment it is shatnez.

> תפר בגד של צמר בשל פשתן, אפילו תפרן במשי, או שתפר בגד צמר בחוטי פשתים, או בגד פשתים בחוטי צמר, או קשר חוט צמר בחוטי פשתן או גידלן, אפילו נתן צמר ופשתים בשק או בקופה וכרכן--הרי אלו כלאיים.
>
> If one stitches wool with linen, even if he connects them with another material ... it is shatnez.

Shulchan Aruch (Y.D. 299:2) rules like the Rambam.

The Rema there argues and holds like the Rash.  Magen Avraham takes this position.

> העושה בגד כולו צמר גמלים או ארנבים או קנבוס וארג בו חוט של צמר מצד זה וחוט של פשתן מצד זה הרי זה אסור משום כלאים:
>
> הגה: וי"א דשרי בכה"ג אלא אם כן ארג חוט של צמר אצל החוט של פשתים אבל אם אינם נוגעים יחד שרי

So if they are not touching each other, even though it is in the same garment, is a dispute.

According to the Rash and Rema, you could have your jacket if there was a separation between.  According to the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch, you could not.

A linen shirt and a wool jacket would be allowed even according to the Rambam (Kilayim 10:11):

> לובש אדם בגד צמר ובגד פשתים, וחוגר עליהם מבחוץ--ובלבד שלא יטרוף את המשיחה, ויקשור בה בין כתפיו

However, the Rema (300:4) brings an opinion that a garment with sleeves is different and one cannot wear a wool one over a linen one, which he says one should be careful for.

> י"א דאסור ללבוש ב' בתי שוקיים א' של פשתן וא' של צמר זו על זו (הגהות אשיר"י פ"ק דביצה) דמאחר דא"א לפשוט התחתונה בלא העליונה הוי כחבור ולא דמי לב' חלוקים זו על זו דאפשר לפשוט התחתון בלא העליון ונכון ליזהר

Answer (score 2):

No, my mother works in the suit industry, and she asked our community rabbi this exact question. He said that as long as it is in the same garment it is impermissible; it does not need to be sewn together. I do not know the sources he used to answer her.